# Разбивка на файлы C++

Tags: c++

В общем я тут попробовал. Вроде следовал советам, но выдает ошибку. Ошибка в мейне. Компилятору не нравятся строки там где `cout` идет. Пишет

">Ошибка    7 error C2679: бинарный "<<": не найден оператор, принимающий правый операнд типа "Fraction" (или приемлемое преобразование отсутствует)"   "

Я делал так:

```
//fraction.h
class Fraction
{
    private:
        int numerator;
        int denominator;
    public:
        Fraction(int numerator, int denominator) : numerator(numerator), denominator(denominator) {}
        int getNumerator() const {
            return numerator;
        }
        int getDenominator() const {
            return denominator;
        }

        Fraction operator+(const Fraction other) ;
Fraction operator-(const Fraction other) ;
        Fraction operator*(const Fraction other) ;
        Fraction operator/(const Fraction other) ;
};
//fraction.cpp
#include"stdafx.h"
#include"fraction.h"
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
Fraction Fraction:: operator+(const Fraction other) {
            if ( denominator == other.denominator ) {
                return Fraction(numerator+other.numerator, denominator);
            }
            int num = numerator * other.denominator + other.numerator * denominator;
            int denom = denominator * other.denominator;
            return Fraction(num, denom);
        }

       Fraction Fraction:: operator-(const Fraction other) {
            if ( denominator == other.denominator ) {
                return Fraction(numerator-other.numerator, denominator);
            }
            int num = numerator * other.denominator - other.numerator * denominator;
            int denom = denominator * other.denominator;
            return Fraction(num, denom);
        }

        Fraction Fraction:: operator*(const Fraction other) {
            return Fraction(numerator * other.numerator, denominator * other.denominator);
        }

       Fraction Fraction::operator/(const Fraction other) {
            return Fraction(numerator * other.denominator, denominator * other.numerator);
        }

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Fraction& fraction)
{
    out << fraction.getNumerator() << "/" << fraction.getDenominator();
    return out;
}
// ConsoleApplication1.cpp: 
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include"fraction.h"
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{ 
    Fraction a(2, 7);
    Fraction b(3, 7);
    Fraction c(2, 9);
    Fraction d(1, 2);
    Fraction e(5, 6);

    std::cout <<"a: " << a << std::endl;
    std::cout << "b: " << b << std::endl;
    std::cout << "c: " << c << std::endl;

    std::cout<< a << " + " << b << " = " << a+b << std::endl;
    std::cout << a << " + " << c << " = " << a+c << std::endl;

    std::cout << b << " - " << a << " = " << b-a << std::endl;
    std::cout << e << " - " << d << " = " << e-d << std::endl;

    std::cout << a << " * " << c << " = " << a*c << std::endl;

    std::cout << a << " / " << b << " = " << a/b << std::endl;
    std::cout << c << " / " << a << " = " << c/a << std::endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Создайте файл **fraction.h**, в него поместите объявление класса и его методов, без реализации.
Создайте файл **fraction.cpp**, в котором есть **#include "fraction.h"**. В этот cpp файл поместите реализацию всех методов.
В основном файле, который у вас сейчас есть, должно остаться только **#include "fraction.h"**, без объявлений  и определений класса, и процедура **main()**

Учтите, что в H-файле **НЕ ДОЛЖНО** содержаться реализации методов класса, иначе получите ошибку при сборке.

Comment: Большое спасибо. Видимо по этому она и не собиралась. Я методы туда тоже вставил.

Comment: Однострочные сеттеры/геттеры можете сделать inline и оставить в H-файле.

Comment: @BigBobo работа компановщика в C++ действительно довольно мутный момент, интуитивно непонятный, и его просто нужно прочувствовать на себе. Удачи в освоении C++ !

Comment: я подозреваю, что я что-то из кода не туда позапихивал. Ведь до разбивки этой все прекрасно компилировалось.